# Custom search using custom fields, post type, and custom taxonomy

Tags: custom-taxonomy, custom-field, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Include custom taxonomy term in search](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2623/include-custom-taxonomy-term-in-search)

I need to create a search on a certian post type and then be able to have a checkboxes and dropdowns to search custom fields and custom taxonomies (categories and tags).

I have started off by creating a form that has a field in it that when sent i use that to filter the search.

So far i can get it to search just that one post type but i do not know how to do multiple custom fields or how to search the taxonomies.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Hope this could help!
Bye

[http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2623/include-custom-taxonomy-term-in-search][1]


  [1]: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2623/include-custom-taxonomy-term-in-search

Carletto