# Is it possible to search authors by profile field?

Tags: search, author

Yeah, is there a way to add a search function that only searches through author profiles?

For example, if someone is searching for authors called John Smith, is there a way to have a search form that ONLY searches in author.php?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extend WordPress search to include user search](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/32687/extend-wordpress-search-to-include-user-search)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Relevanssi](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/relevanssi/) - Uncheck all boxes except for "Index and search your Authors" - see screenshot below.

[image: Relevanssi Screenshot]

Comment: That's awesome. Would that work with other fields aswell as the name field?

Would it index authors by the "AIM" field for example?

Answer (score 1):

The relevanssi option is fine if you do not need any other kind of search on your site.
If you want to keep your normal search and have a separate user search, you could try doing something with free amr-users plugin that offers [user list and user search](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/amr-users/).  You define the data that is okay to have public in a list (from the use and user meta table, including data that other plugins may have created) and then there is a search option that will search just within that list