# Jigoshop search taxonomy

Tags: plugins, search, jigoshop

I was wondering does anyone know how I can modify the search so it searches a taxonomy?

at the moment it just looks for a product title, but not the taxonomy assigned to the post.

Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2623/include-custom-taxonomy-term-in-search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change the query settings before it is run. I'm assuming that you have a `search.php` page, but if not I'll tell you where to put the code at the end.

In `search.php` add this to the very top of the file (above the `get_header()` call) -

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => get_option('posts_per_page'),
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_type' => $post_type, // The post type that you wish to search
    $taxonomy => $term // Where $taxonomy is say 'cheese' and $term (must use the slug) is maybe 'cheddar'. Can be omitted if you do not actually wish to search taxonomy/terms. I think you can also pass $term as an array of terms - array('cheddar', 'brie', 'edam').
);
```

If you do not have `search.php`, nest the code as below and place it at the top of your `index.php` file -

```
if(is_search()) :
    { Code from above goes here }
endif;
```

Comment: I don't understand what an array could do to it, but it doesn't seem to work, I also added `$wp_query = new WP_Query($args);` on the search.php file but with no luck

Comment: I thought that if you had a `search.php` file Wordpress would automatically pass the $args, but perhaps not. It could be worth trying `query_posts($args);` directly under the `$args` array.

Answer (score 0):

You should search for duplicate questions, this question was asked here:

[Include custom taxonomy term in search](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2623/include-custom-taxonomy-term-in-search)

The answer is: Use the **Search Everything** plugin