# Extending search query with additional $sentence value

Tags: search, mysql

Next in my quest to extend WordPress is altering how WordPress uses the the `$sentence` variable in `posts_search` to include an additional string, when the `$sentence` variable meets a certain criteria.

The specific usecase here is that when someone types in something like `TL123` it should also search for `TL-123`, with `TL%` being the wildcard here. This is to cut-down on search mistakes (for those that do not include the hyphen).

I've seen how we can filter into `posts_search` with additional SQL queries (I'm actually using [this one](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2623/include-custom-taxonomy-term-in-search) with pretty good success so far), but am a little fuzzy on how this could work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

*Edit - to include more information about needs thanks to @kaiser*

- Searches are typically done by typing in *TL123*, when in reality the actual post title is *TL-123* in most cases - so, the goal here is to intercept when the search query includes *TL*(NUMBER) and also search *TL-*(NUMBER).

Again, the trick here is that some posts do not include TL- but only TL, so that's why I'm looking for search queries that match that pattern to also search an additional "partial phrase".

Thanks!

## Update

Alright, so based off of kaiser's starter function, I have come up with the following:

```
function wpse66815_search_query_string( $search, &$wp_query )
{
    if (!is_admin() && is_search()) {

        print_r($search);

        global $wp_query;

        // get search term
        $search_term = array_shift($wp_query->query_vars['search_terms']);
        // specify string we'll use to replace
        $replace_var = 'TL';

        // find matches for that string
        preg_match_all("/{$replace_var}(?:[^0-9]*)(\d+)/i", $search_term, $out);

        // if there's no matches, return the normal search
        if ( empty($out[0]) )
            return $search;

        // find/generate the search term with the replacement
        $modified_search_term = preg_replace("/{$replace_var}(?:[^0-9]*)(\d+)/i", "{$replace_var}-$1", $search_term);

        // combine both the regular and modified search term
        $new_search[] = $search_term;
        $new_search[] = $modified_search_term;

        //var_dump($new_search);

        // generate the new search query
        foreach ( $new_search as $keyword )
        {
            $new_string_parts[] = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->prepare(
                 "
                    AND ((%s.post_title LIKE '%%%s%%') OR (%s.post_content LIKE '%%%s%%'))
                 "
                ,"{$GLOBALS['wpdb']->prefix}posts"
                ,like_escape( $keyword )
                ,"{$GLOBALS['wpdb']->prefix}posts"
                ,like_escape( $keyword )
            );
        }

        // set $search equal to results
        $search = implode( " ", $new_string_parts );

        //print_r($search);
    }

    return $search;
}
add_filter('posts_search', 'wpse66815_search_query_string',500,2);
```

The part that I can't get past is actually is the actual SQL query -> error below:

`WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.post_title LIKE 'tl123') OR ('wp__posts'.post_content LIKE 'tl123')) ' at line 2]`

`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND (('wp__posts'.post_title LIKE 'tl123') OR ('wp__posts'.post_content LIKE 'tl123')) AND (('wp__posts'.post_title LIKE 'TL-123') OR ('wp__posts'.post_content LIKE 'TL-123')) AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment', 'galleries', 'idea_gallery', 'moulding_profiles', 'moulding_collection', 'moulding_combination') AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_author = 2 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 80`

Any pointers on where I went wrong? Thanks!

## Update #2

I've started to see a few issues:

- It was doing `wp__posts` instead of `wp_posts` (I updated that above)
- As `kaiser` mentioned, the `LIKE %s` portion may need to be `LIKE %%s%` but that is not parsing correctly.

Error is now:

`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND (('wp_posts'.post_title LIKE 'tl123') OR ('wp_posts'.post_content LIKE 'tl123')) AND (('wp_posts'.post_title LIKE 'TL-123') OR ('wp_posts'.post_content LIKE 'TL-123')) AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment', 'galleries', 'idea_gallery', 'moulding_profiles', 'moulding_collection', 'moulding_combination') AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_author = 2 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 80`

The error above (from what I can tell) is actually trying to look for a post that is both `tl123` and `TL-123`, but I think `OR` is what I want (as I want to return posts in an either or situation).

## Update #3

Updated function to properly escape `%s`, so error is now:

`WordPress database error: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.post_title LIKE '%tl123%') OR ('wp_posts'.post_content LIKE '%tl123%')) ' at line 2]`

`SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND (('wp_posts'.post_title LIKE '%tl123%') OR ('wp_posts'.post_content LIKE '%tl123%')) AND (('wp_posts'.post_title LIKE '%TL-123%') OR ('wp_posts'.post_content LIKE '%TL-123%')) AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment', 'galleries', 'idea_gallery', 'moulding_profiles', 'moulding_collection', 'moulding_combination') AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_author = 2 AND wp_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 80`

## Update #4

Here's what I ended up doing -> the foreach wasn't wrapping correctly (with the AND/OR operator as @kaiser mentioned), so I separated them out into their own array insertions.

```
function wpse66815_search_query_string( $search, &$wp_query )
{
    if (!is_admin() && is_search()) {

        //print_r($search);

        global $wp_query,$wpdb;

        // get search term
        $search_term = array_shift($wp_query->query_vars['search_terms']);
        // specify string we'll use to replace
        $replace_var = 'TL';

        // find matches for that string
        preg_match_all("/{$replace_var}(?:[^0-9]*)(\d+)/i", $search_term, $out);

        // if there's no matches, return the normal search
        if ( empty($out[0]) )
            return $search;

        // find/generate the search term with the replacement
        $modified_search_term = preg_replace("/{$replace_var}(?:[^0-9]*)(\d+)/i", "{$replace_var}-$1", $search_term);

        // combine both the regular and modified search term
        $new_search[] = $search_term;
        $new_search[] = $modified_search_term;

        var_dump($new_search);

        // generate the new search query
        $new_string_parts[] = $wpdb->prepare( "AND ((({$wpdb->posts}.post_title LIKE '%%%s%%') OR ({$wpdb->posts}.post_content LIKE '%%%s%%'))",like_escape( $new_search[0] ),like_escape( $new_search[0] ));
        $new_string_parts[] = $wpdb->prepare( "OR (({$wpdb->posts}.post_title LIKE '%%%s%%') OR ({$wpdb->posts}.post_content LIKE '%%%s%%')))",like_escape( $new_search[1] ),like_escape( $new_search[1] ));

        // set $search equal to results
        $search = implode( " ", $new_string_parts );

        //print_r($search);
    }

    return $search;
}
add_filter('posts_search', 'wpse66815_search_query_string',500,2);
```

It does have some trouble if someone were to type in `tl123 tl456` (two occurences of the `tl` keyword), but I'm working on that portion. Thanks!

Comment: Please add more details about what "divides" a search string. Is it every non alpha(numeric?) character? If so, then simply split the string and add all those as `LIKE` escaped by `like_escape()`.

Comment: @kaiser Done - good idea. Am a bit new to SQL queries, so it's not a call for "doing it for me", but rather examples that I can build off of or an explanation of how this could theoretically work (plugging into and adding terms into the `$sentence` variable). I definitely want to learn, but we sometimes all need a nudge (more like a shove here). Thanks!

Comment: So if string would be `AB123CD-45`, then the `LIKE´ parst would be `array( 'AB', '123', 'CD', '45' );`? In other words: Split the search query string in numbers and letters?

Comment: More if the `$sentence` has `TL` (then a number), like `TL123`, no matter what else is attached in the `$sentence`, it should also search for `TL-123`. For example, `TL123 Supercallafrajalistic Expialadocious` would also search `TL-123 Supercallafrajalistic Expialadocious` or `TL123withwords` will also search `TL-123withwords`. `TLmoreletters` would only search `TLmoreletters` (as that could be a regular word)

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the problem is the quotes around `'wp_posts'` and the brackets around AND/OR.

Comment: @kaiser Been trying a few things with no luck, have a moment to show me what you think the correct syntax would be? I really appreciate it.

Comment: If I hardcode in the first portion (about locating the posts table), http://pastebin.com/WU0drDjy it is actually returning every post I have on the site. Could you let me know where you're seeing the other error again? The brackets portion.

Comment: Thanks for awarding the bounty that early. From a look at your pastebin, I'd say the problem starts with not using `$wpdb->posts` for the prepare part. And in "Update 3", I see the brackets problem.

Comment: [Come here, so we can do this live](https://www.stypi.com/kaiser/Zach%20WPSE).

Comment: Hey @kaiser I kept sending messages but you must not have been able to see them. If you do have anymore time, I'm there still

Comment: I was sending them too, but it seems it didn't work out as we expected. Sorry to say, but I need to get my work done now. Maybe another day this week. Just stay in chat and you'll meet me there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gladly I've written two plugins for that yesterday:

### Filter/Core

That's what a search query part looks like inside the `posts_search` filter:

```
' AND (((wp_XX_posts.post_title LIKE '%test%') OR (wp_XX_posts.post_content LIKE '%test%'))) '
```

where `wp_XX_` is just the `$wpdb->prefix` for my WPSE test site inside my local MU installation.

### Plugin #1 - drop searching post types that we don't need.

Here's a plugin modifying the searched post types, as this is needed often.

```
<?php
/** Plugin Name: (#66815) »kaiser« Limit search query post types */

/**
 * Alter the searched post types
 * 
 * @param  object $query
 * @return object $query
 */
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse66815_pre_get_posts' );
function wpse66815_pre_get_posts( $query )
{
    if ( $query->is_main_query() )
    {
        $query->set( 'post_type', 'YOUR_POST_TYPE' );
    }

    return $query;
}
```

### Plugin #2 - modify the search string

Now, that we know how the default search string for the post title and content looks, we just have to rebuild it the way we need it:

```
<?php 
/** Plugin Name: (#66815) »kaiser« Modify search query string */

function wpse66815_search_query_string( $search_string )
{
    global $wpdb;

    $searched_for = preg_match_all(
        // Match a prefix (%), but exclude it from the capture
        // Any character, any number of repetitions
        // Match a suffix (%), but exclude it from the capture
        "/(?<=\%)(.*)(?=\%)/",
        $search_string,
        $search_string_matches
    );

    // We only need one element
    $searched_for = array_shift( $search_string_matches );

    // Now we need to search for [LETTERS (min 1)][NUMBER (zero or more)][CHARACTER (zero or more)]
    preg_match_all(
        "/([^a-zA-Z][\d+]*[-_ ]*)/",
        $searched_for,
        $string_part_matches
    );

    // Here we now got matches - if not, we can simply abort and leave the default
    $searched_for = array_shift( $string_part_matches );
    if ( empty( $searched_for ) )
        return $search_string;

    // Finally we need to split the string by all parts that are allowed
    // YOU NEED TO EDIT MY ANSWER HERE AND FILL IN WHAT WORKS FOR YOU
    $keywords = preg_split(
         "/([\s]*[\d+]*[-_ ]*)/",
         $searched_for,
         -1, // 0 & -1 are NO limit
         PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE
    );

    // Now loop and build an array for further processing
    // Our first search string is - of course - the default string
    $string_parts = array( $search_string );
    foreach ( $keywords as $keyword )
    {
        $new_string_parts[] = $GLOBALS['wpdb']->prepare(
            " AND ((%s.post_title LIKE '%s') OR (%s.post_content LIKE '%s')) ",
            $wpdb->posts,
            $wpdb->esc_like( $keyword ),
            $wpdb->posts,
            $wpdb->esc_like( $keyword )
        );
    }

    // Now lets glue them together, return and see what we get...
    return implode( " ", $new_string_parts );
}
```

This 2<sup>nd</sup> plugin is untested, as my needs are different and I guess some of the regexes are not completely what you need - you'll have to fix that and update this answer (this is your part in "giving the community back" in this Q/A). A nice tool to build regex, that I just found, is [**Expresso**](http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm). It's damn ugly (as the web presence), but extremely helpful.

Comment: Hm. Not sure if it shouldn't be `'%%s%'` instead...

Comment: Really appreciate it @kaiser will do some testing and report back

Comment: Updated my original question with progress