# Custom search for custom post type, custom meta and search fields

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, search

Id like to build a search form for a specific custom post type (vehicle) and have filters for that custom posts type's custom meta fields (price, age) and custom taxonomies (make). This will totally replace the sites search and be the only search available so I was going to use search.php within my custom template.

I've like the search to look something like:

**Search our vehicles**

**Make** (select box full of all the custom taxonomies - Audi, BMW etc).

**Model** (normal input field for people to type whatever in).

**Prices over** (select box with prices starting at 1000)

**Age** (select box with options such as under 1 year, under 3 years, under 5 years, under 10 years).

I'm new to custom fields and dont really know where to start (I've found a few examples on Google but none do exactly what I'm aiming for). I didnt really want to use a plugin either. I'm guessing within search.php I grab the data passed from the form and use it to build $args up to pass to WP_Query?

Could someone point me in the right direction please? Thanks in advance

Comment: [Have you seen this answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66815/extending-search-query-with-additional-sentence-value/66904#66904)?

Comment: I'd not but it seems massively complex for what I'm trying to do?

Comment: "massively complex" means you don't want read that much text, right? :P Please read it. It will bring you down half the way minimum.

Comment: Any progress on that question?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to extend your query, you should extend it through the `pre_get_posts`-filter. Then just do a ["Custom Field" or meta query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters).

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse105969_extended_search' );
function wpse105969_extended_search( $query )
{
    // Make sure we got a search query
    // and we're only modifying the main query.
    if (
        ! $query->is_main_query()
        AND '' === $query->get( 's' )
        AND 'your_custom_post_type' === $query->get( 'post_type' )
    )
        return $query;

    // Alter whatever you need: Make, Model, etc.
    $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'color',
            'value'   => 'blue',
            'compare' => 'NOT LIKE'
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'price',
            'value'   => array( 20, 100 ),
            'type'    => 'numeric',
            'compare' => 'BETWEEN'
        )
    ) );

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer - I dont actually use the 's' field that normal wordpress searches require (im only search for the custom post types meta details). Is there anyway to NOT use the 's' field in the search form, struggling to find info on this. Thanks again.

Comment: Also, I've added your code to my functions.php and added in my fields but when i save it breaks wordpress (no errors). Nothing from wordpress works (nav, posts etc).

Comment: @JamesJ Please post an update with _your_ code. Hint: Did you change the custom post type name and did you set `WP_DEBUG` to `true`?

Answer (score 1):

Here’s the code. You can change `$post_type` and `$custom_fields` according to your needs.

```
function extend_admin_search( $query ) {

    // Extend search for document post type
    $post_type = 'document';
    // Custom fields to search for
    $custom_fields = array(
        "_file_name",
    );

    if( ! is_admin() )
        return;

    if ( $query->query['post_type'] != $post_type )
        return;

    $search_term = $query->query_vars['s'];

    // Set to empty, otherwise it won't find anything
    $query->query_vars['s'] = '';

    if ( $search_term != '' ) {
        $meta_query = array( 'relation' => 'OR' );

        foreach( $custom_fields as $custom_field ) {
            array_push( $meta_query, array(
                'key' => $custom_field,
                'value' => $search_term,
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            ));
        }

        $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
    };
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'extend_admin_search' );
```