# Get posts by meta value

Tags: post-meta

I would like to list all posts that have a key of `cp_annonceur` with the value `professionnel`.

Comment: Please be aware that [you are expected to have researched the problem and made an attempt at solving it before posting a question.](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/how-to-ask) Had you not been brand new here I would have probably down-voted the question and moved on, rather than answer it. In the spirit of "Welcome to the Stack" this is your free-bee. Please take a look at [ask] for future questions.

Answer (score 80):

What you are asking for is a `meta_query`

```
$args = array(
   'meta_key' => 'custom-meta-key',
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'cp_annonceur',
           'value' => 'professionnel',
           'compare' => '=',
       )
   )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

[All of the information you need is in the Codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/).

Comment: @Beginner : if this solved the problem please mark it "Accepted". Look for the check mark near the vote arrows on the left.

Comment: For some reason using `new WP_Query($args)` and then calling `get_posts` doesn't work for me. Directly passing the `$args` array to the `get_posts` function as an argument works however.

Comment: @Kunal You don't need to call get_posts.
Use the code above, and get the posts like so: `$query->posts`. It should return an array.
Don't forget to read the link in the comment, as there is something missing in the code:
```$args = array(
    'post_type'  => 'your-cpt',
    'meta_key'   => 'your-meta',
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'cp_annonceur',
           'value' => 'professionnel',
           'compare' => '=',
       )
   )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);```

Comment: @s_ha_dum minor syntax correction - missing `,` after `'custom-meta-key'`. Would have editied, but it's not possible to make a 1 character edit...

Comment: What's the difference between meta_key and key ?

Comment: This would be wrong. Why would you pass meta_key and then key?
It is not how the WP Query Doc describes it.
What you probably wanted to say is something like
```
'post_type'  => 'product',
 'meta_query' => array(
  array(
   'key'     => 'color',
   'value'   => 'blue',
   'compare' => 'NOT LIKE',
  ),
 ),
```
?

Answer (score 16):

There are two ways to do that:

1. Intercept the main query on `pre_get_posts`:

   ```
   add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query )
   {
       // only handle the main query
       if ( ! $query->is_main_query() )
           return;

       $query->set( 'meta_key',   'cp_annonceur' );
       $query->set( 'meta_value', 'professionnel' );
   } );
   ```
2. Add an additional query

   ```
   $second_loop = get_posts( array(
       'meta_key'   => 'cp_annonceur',
       'meta_value' => 'professionnel',
   ) );
   ```

A more throughout example can be found in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/105705/385).

Comment: Nice to know the short way with get_posts()

Comment: How do you do this with multiple meta ket/values ?

Comment: @G-J you might  want to take a look  at [this example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/105705/385).

Answer (score 12):

I used custom select (might be better performance)

```
$posts = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $wpdb->postmeta
WHERE meta_key = 'cp_annonceur' AND  meta_value = 'professionnel' LIMIT 1", ARRAY_A);
```

Inspired from https://tommcfarlin.com/get-post-id-by-meta-value/

Comment: It might have better performances, but it throws away the whole idea of having Wordpress functions to search (and cache) data. And, also, what will happen if WP decides to change the table structure? :)

Comment: @ErenorPaz I understand what you are saying but this way would make it easy if you had multiple meta key/values as a criteria... Is there an official way to handle multiple criteria?

Comment: You mean something like `WHERE metatable1.meta_key = 'cp_annonceur' AND  metatable1.meta_value = 'professionnel' AND metatable2.meta_key = 'cp_other_meta' AND  metatable2.meta_value = 'other_value'`? (Note that i suppose we do a join on the same posts_meta table using two names `metatable1` and `metatable2`). This can be achieved adding field `meta_query` (as an array) to the query. Take a look at: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters and go to paragraph "‘orderby’ with multiple ‘meta_key’s"

Answer (score 8):

We can get the desired result with Meta query of the WordPress :

```
// the meta_key 'diplay_on_homepage' with the meta_value 'true'
$cc_args = array(
    'posts_per_page'   => -1,
    'post_type'        => 'post',
    'meta_key'         => 'cp_annonceur',
    'meta_value'       => 'professionnel'
);
$cc_query = new WP_Query( $cc_args );
```

For more detailed guide regarding meta query follow this blog : http://www.codecanal.com/get-posts-meta-values/

Comment: May i know why this `post_per_page` value is -1?

Comment: @AbhayGawade You can limit max number of results using that parameter, -1 means no limit.

Comment: Thanks man works fine. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can easily grab the posts using WordPress's built-in function called **get_posts**
You can find more details about **get_posts** here https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/

```php
$posts = get_posts(array(
    'numberposts'   => -1,
    'post_type'     => 'post',
    'meta_key'      => 'cp_annonceur',
    'meta_value'    => 'professionnel'
));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, It's working for me

```
global $wpdb;
$meta_key = '_request_body';

$data = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare( "SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM $wpdb->postmeta WHERE meta_key = %s", $meta_key) , ARRAY_N  );

$result = [];
foreach($data as $array){
    $result[] = $array[0];
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: That would list the distinct possible values, which isn't quite what the question asks for.

Comment: You should never access the database for such fundamental WP things as getting posts. You should always use abstracted WP-API which does all the heavy lifting for you and ensures your code will work if anything is changed under the hood.