# Selecting posts with a given meta value for a meta key

Tags: wp-query, meta-query

I'm trying to run a query that returns all the posts with a given value for a specific meta key. I know for a fact that this is none of the posts on my test server but it reports finding all the posts with a post count of 7 (there are 21 posts).

I have been following the notes [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/) and the question [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/80303/109240) but I cannot get a sensible outcome.

```
    $args = array(
            'post_type'  => 'post',
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',// outcome is the same with and without this line
                array(
                    'key'     => 'perma',
                    'compare' => '=', 
                    'value'   => "{$raw_perma}"
                ),
            ),
        );

    // create a custom query
    $my_query = new \WP_Query( $args );
    
    
    echo $my_query->post_count; // 7 (regardless of $raw_perma value).
```

I would like to know what I am doing wrong. As "are there posts with this meta key-value pair?" seems like it should be a trivial question to answer.

**Update**

Found [another question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/281832/109240) and tried this:

```
    $args = array(
                'posts_per_page'   => -1,
                'post_type'        => 'post',
                'meta_key'         => 'perma',
                'meta_value'       => "{$raw_perma}"
            );
```

This works although I have no idea why this and not that. Would like to see an explanation in an answer.

Comment: Why are you using 'relation' => 'AND', for the meta_query?

Comment: @QStudio in the hope that it might work. I have got to the point where I trying daft things because I just don't know what the issue is.

Comment: Perhaps go back to basics, and show the code you think should work - also show how $raw_perma is generated, and for good measures, make a SQL query directly to phpmyadmin showing the right / expected results - to ensure this is not a data issue.

Comment: I have had a PHPMyAdmin tab open the entire time. It's not a data issue as far as I can tell.

Comment: Guessing, remove the AND and remove the compare - this is redundant - and read this post, might help: https://rudrastyh.com/wordpress/meta_query.html

Comment: Also, what is the value of {$raw_perma} ?

Comment: It's the permalink to a post from another site that one and only one post will be twinned with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This works although I have no idea why this and not that. Would like to see an explanation in an answer.

Because that code sets the `posts_per_page` value to `-1` which means no limit and it's similar to setting `nopaging` to `true`, hence all found posts are returned.

> it reports finding all the posts with a post count of 7 (there are 21 posts)

I think the original issue here is that you probably not aware that the property `$post_count` (i.e. `WP_Query::$post_count`) is actually the number of posts just for the current page, so if `LIMIT` was used (in the SQL statement generated by `WP_Query`), e.g. by setting the `posts_per_page` value to, say, `10` which is the default value, then the `$post_count` would be `10` *or less* depending on the total number of posts in the database which matched the specific query.

So if you want to get that total number, then use the `$found_posts` property:

```php
$my_query = new \WP_Query( array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1, // just for testing
) );

echo "Number of posts with LIMIT applied: {$my_query->post_count}<br>";

echo "Number of posts without LIMIT applied: {$my_query->found_posts}";
```

See [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#properties) if you'd like to check the other properties in `WP_Query`.

### Additional Notes

1. If you don't set the `posts_per_page` in your query args, the value will default to `10` or whatever you put in the "Blog pages show at most" input on the Reading Settings admin page (`wp-admin` → Settings → Reading). And I guessed you had it set to `7`?
2. I think that `"{$raw_perma}"` could simply be written as `$raw_perma` as in `'meta_value' => $raw_perma` and `'value' => $raw_perma` .. :)