# custom autocomplete search

Tags: ajax, search, autocomplete

I try to implement an autocomplete search but I have some troubles to make it works correctly.

When I write in search input some words, the autocomplete search doesn't filter the results and always display all my posts. So it doesn't search at all...

And I've also some difficulties to understand the way to display custom result, like the tumbnail, the title and the category for each finded post.

Here my scripts:

```
require_once ($admin_path . "search_autocomplete.php");

function search_ac_init() {  
    wp_enqueue_script( 'search_ac', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/search_ac.js', array('jquery','jquery-ui-autocomplete'),null,true); 
    wp_localize_script( 'search_ac', 'MyAcSearch', array('url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));
} 
add_action( 'init', 'search_ac_init' );
```

in search_autocomplete.php :

```
<?php

add_action( 'wp_ajax_search_autocomplete', 'search_autocomplete' );  
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_search_autocomplete', 'search_autocomplete' ); 

function search_autocomplete(){  
    $posts = get_posts( array(  
        'search' =>$_REQUEST['term'],  
    ) );   
    $suggestions=array();  
    global $post;  
    $args = array('post_type' => array('post', 'portfolio'), 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'post_status'  => 'publish');
    $myposts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ($myposts as $post): setup_postdata($post);  
        $suggestion = array();  
        $suggestion['label'] = esc_html($post->post_title);  
        $suggestion['link'] = get_permalink();  
        $suggestions[]= $suggestion;  
    ?>  

    //<a class="link" href="<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>");>
        //<div class="img">
            //<img class="<?php echo  wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id()); ?>"/ >
        //</div>
        //<div class="title"><?php echo the_title(); ?></div>
        //<div class="post"><?php echo $post_type; ?></div>
    //</a>
    // I want to display like above
    <?php   
    endforeach;  
    $response = $_GET["callback"] . "(" . json_encode($suggestions) . ")";  
    echo $response;    
    exit;  
}  

?>
```

and search_ac.js :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){  
    var acs_action = 'search_autocomplete';  
    $("input#search").autocomplete({  
        minLength: 3,
        source: function(req, response){  
            $.getJSON(MyAcSearch.url+'?callback=?&action='+acs_action, req, response);  
        },  
        select: function(event, ui) {  
            window.location.href=ui.item.link; 
        },    
        open: function(event,ui){
            var len = $('.ui-autocomplete > li').length;
            var ImgAtocompleteWidth = 60*(1/ratio);
            $(".image-autocomplete").width(ImgAtocompleteWidth);
            $('#input-count').show();
            $('#clearInput').show();
            if (len==1) {
                $('#input-count').html(len+' result');
            } else {
                $('#input-count').html(len+' results');
                }
            },
        close: function( event, ui ){   
            $('#input-count').html('')
                             .hide();
            $('#clearInput').hide(100);
            if( $('#noMatches').is(':visible') ) {
                    $('#clearInput').show(100); 
            }       
        },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
            titleinput = ui.item.value;
            ui.item.value= $.trim(titleinput);
            $( "input#search" ).val( ui.item.value );
            $('#input-count').show();
            return false;
        },      
    }).focus(function(event, ui){
            $(this).autocomplete("search");
        })  
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ajax and autocomplete](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/37202/ajax-and-autocomplete)

Comment: Not sure because my autocomplete seems to work. But the php term seems to don't works. Whatever I type in search field it always show all my database...

Comment: You really don't want to use `$_REQUEST['term']` in a database query. At least not without escaping the input... Anyway, just go with Stephens answer. It's plain perfect. Also look at [my answer over here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66815/extending-search-query-with-additional-sentence-value/66904#66904) on how to do `LIKE` queries with a search.

Comment: thank you for your help. I'm new in wordpress. I should avoid using `$_REQUEST['term']`? In stephens answer request is also use and also in every blog that I read on autocomplete for msyql... I try with stephens script but it's not working at all.

Comment: Yeah, the first thing is that ***everyone escapes input*** from `GET/POST/REQUEST` or form fields, as it else is unsafe and you can easily hack into your database and `DROP TABLE` all the things. Not kool. The second thing is, that you need to _update your question_ with your new code. Hint: Copypasta never works out -> type it char by char and try to understand what happens. Hint #2: _"it's not working at all"_ is ***not*** a proper error description and no one wants to _guess_ what happened, right?

Comment: Ok. I don't have any error in my console. I'm near sure that I have a problem to get input text typed in my form. I can't print the request term. I don't understand the interaction between my input form an php... Actually with my question script, I have no errors and when I search the autocomplete works but append all my post whatever is typed in the search field. By the way sorry for my english, I'm french.

Comment: English isn't my mother tongue as well. Make sure that you have [debug turned on](https://gist.github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/4063197). Btw, the comment form is already telling that our discussion is too lengthy. Maybe you want to try it in chat.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9613/discussion-between-freaky-and-kaiser)

Answer (score 2):

I found my problem.

It was just a problem from my search php script! Without `trim( $_REQUEST['term'] )` it will not correctly filter results.

Now like this it works perfectly:

```
function search_autocomplete(){ 

    $posts = get_posts( array(
            's' => trim( $_REQUEST['term'] ), 'post_type' => array('post', 'portfolio')
        ) );
    $suggestions=array();

    global $post;

    $args = array('post_type' => array('post', 'portfolio'), 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'post_status'  => 'publish');
    $post = get_posts($args);

    foreach ($posts as $post): 
        setup_postdata($post);
        $suggestion = array();
        $suggestion['label'] = esc_html($post->post_title);
        $suggestion['link'] = get_permalink();
        $suggestions[]= $suggestion;
    endforeach;

    $response = $_GET["callback"] . "(" . json_encode($suggestions) . ")";  
    echo $response;  
    exit;
}
```