# How to add additional search terms (e.g. synonyms) to the search?

Tags: search, tags

I'm running a blog about different software tools. I frequently use the search to find articles that I wrote for the blog. I also wrote an article about `latexdiff`, but always forget the name and try for example `difftex` which gives no results in the search.

I thought, that adding a tag `difftex` might solve the problem, without disturbing the main article by adding e.g. a sentence "I sometimes mix it up with difftex, difflatex,...".

But I found out, that tags are not used for the search. What is the **golden way** to add terms to the search?

Answer (score 0):

I think your question has already been [asked](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2623/include-custom-taxonomy-term-in-search). You can add additional terms as post tags, and then these tags can be added to the search query via filters. See [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/5404/8521).