# Include tags in WP_Query

Tags: wp-query, search, tags

I found several posts about it. Others said that you cannot do it without a plugin and others that it is possible. However, I am not sure what is true :P

This is my query and unfortunately, I cannot make it return objects with a certain tag.

```
<?php
global $query_string;

$query_args = explode("&", $query_string);
$search_query = array();

foreach($query_args as $key => $string) {
    $query_split = explode("=", $string);
    $search_query[$query_split[0]] = urldecode($query_split[1]);
}

$search = new WP_Query($search_query);
?>
```

Any idea how I can modify the query to include also the tags without a plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution may work for you also [Include custom taxonomy term in search](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2623/include-custom-taxonomy-term-in-search)

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not what I am asking. What you suggest is to have a query in the format of `/?s=keyword&tag=tagexample`...However, I have a simple search form with the query `/?s=keyword`..I want to search for this keyword, both in titles, contents and tags.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand your post correctly. Maybe this solution will fit your nees http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2623/include-custom-taxonomy-term-in-search

Comment: This seems that works from the first check. Give me some time to test it thoroughly and till then, please update your answer so I can accept it if it really works.