# Search only custom taxonomies

Tags: custom-taxonomy, search

I created a custom taxonomy called `people`. In the meantime there are over 2k people available in this taxonomy. Now I want to make it possible to search for a person, e.g. I search for `John`, I want to receive all persons with that name. I'm a little bit confused how to archieve this and how to add the taxonomy to the search results.

I create the taxonomy with register_taxonomy

```
register_taxonomy('people','post',array(
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'labels' => $labels,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'show_admin_column' => true,
    'update_count_callback' => '_update_post_term_count',
    'query_var' => true,
    'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'people' ),
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'rest_controller_class' => 'WP_REST_Terms_Controller'
));
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.*
FROM   wp_posts
   LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships
          ON ( wp_posts.id = wp_term_relationships.object_id )
   LEFT JOIN wp_term_relationships tr
          ON wp_posts.id = tr.object_id
   INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy tt
           ON tt.term_taxonomy_id = tr.term_taxonomy_id
   INNER JOIN wp_terms t
           ON t.term_id = tt.term_id    
WHERE  1 = 1
   AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN ( 2, 3 ) )
   AND ( ( ( wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%Johnny%' )
            OR ( wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%John%' )
            OR ( wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%John%' ) )
         AND ( ( wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%John%' )
                OR ( wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%John%' )
                OR ( wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%John%' ) ) )
   AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
   AND (( wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' ))
    OR ( t.name LIKE '%John%' )
GROUP  BY wp_posts.id
ORDER  BY ( CASE
          WHEN wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%John%' THEN 1
          WHEN wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%John%'
               AND wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%John%' THEN 2
          WHEN wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%John%'
                OR wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%John%' THEN 3
          WHEN wp_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%John%' THEN 4
          WHEN wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%John%' THEN 5
          ELSE 6
        end ),
      wp_posts.post_date DESC
LIMIT  0, 99
```

EDIT 2:
It seems like I have to do sth. like this

```
SELECT * FROM wp_terms WHERE name LIKE "%John%"
```

If I'm totally wrong with this opinion, i would like to here your suggestions.

Comment: You create a taxonomy through register_post_type()? Check the parameters: public and exclude_from_search

Comment: I use register_taxonomy to create the taxonomy https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_taxonomy . I didn't see an option to exlude / include it to search.

Comment: What are the parameters  public and exclude_from_search ?

Comment: I updated the post with the parameters. Everything else is set to default

Comment: Look at this question: [link](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2623/include-custom-taxonomy-term-in-search)

Comment: I tried that already, but I only get the posts as result. I added `t.*` to the select clause, but cause of the JOIN i only receive the tags associated with the post

Answer (score 1):

Create a search form that submits a field called "name". In the file that handles form submissions,

```
// get the "name" the visitor searched for
$term = $_POST['name'];

// query: find all posts with the 'people' taxonomy set to the "name" they searched for
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post', // or insert your custom post type here
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'people',
            'field'    => 'slug',
            'terms'    => "$sterm"
        ),
    ),
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// loop through results and display
if($query->have_posts()):
    while($query->have_posts()) : $query->the_post();

    // output whatever HTML you like here
    ?><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><?php

    endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: I don't want to search the post which are associated with the the given taxonomy. I want to search the taxonomies itself excluding all posts.