# Searching in wordpress using wp_term_taxonomy table

Tags: taxonomy, search-engines

I have been trying for some time now to return search results not only of products from woocommerce but also for anything that is found on the rest of my site. If you search for SKU "4110-26" then it jumps straight to the product however it doesn't show any pages where the text "4110-26" can be found. The text I want to search is mainly kept in the wp_term_taxonomy table in the MySQL data base. Is there a way I can have not only the products shown in the search result but also links to other text found.

Many thanks
Iain

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Include custom taxonomy term in search](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/2623/include-custom-taxonomy-term-in-search)

Comment: Hi, Yes I have and still no joy.